# Three.js force the shadow of a rotating 2D plane to always face the light source

Tags: three.js, shadows

I have a 2D plane with a tree texture that always faces the general direction of the camera by rotating only on its Y axis.  It works great and the shadows are cast perfectly, but I don't want the shadow of the 2D plane to rotate with it.

I'd like the shadow to appear so that the 2D object is always facing directly at a light source even when its not.  I've tried messing with shaders without any luck.  Should I be investigating shader tricks with this, or is there already something available from within Three.js that can do this already?

I was thinking it's that or come up with an invisible plane at the same position of the other 2D plane, and force it to face the light source and cast shadows, but that would cause other complications.

The reason for needing this is to keep thick, bushy shadows for 2D trees in a scene.

Comment: three.js cannot defy laws of physics!

Comment: how about you add another plane, at 90deg from the original one, render it in the shadow map, but not in the final frame?

Comment: oh come on gaitat, 3d is approximating and faking physics, we just use it as a guideline :)